# How to login to neopets.com through GM userscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey-4

I created a userscript which starts at the Neopets [login page](http://www.neopets.com/login/) and autofills the username and password. I am having trouble getting the script to click the giant green "LOG IN" button.

```js
$('input[name=username']).val('username_here');
$('input[name=password']).val('password_here');
```

I have tried all of the following to click the login button or submit the form.

```js
//None of these clicked the sign in button:
$("input.submit[name = 'welcomeLoginButton']").submit();
$("input.submit[name = 'welcomeLoginButton']").click();
$('body').on('click','welcomeLoginButton',function(){alert('logged in?');});
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.submit[name = 'welcomeLoginButton']"))).click();
```

I know there's no element named 'welcomeLoginButton' and only a class named `.welcomeLoginButton`. How can I get the form to submit itself after the username and password have been filled?

Comment: What's wrong with `document.getElementsByClassName("welcomeLoginButton")[0].click()`? (`.click()` isn't just a jQuery thing) **Edit:** you could also just use `$('.welcomeLoginButton')[0].click()`

Comment: @Samathingamajig Thanks so much, both of those worked! Could you post that as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the list of all the elements with the class `welcomeLoginButton` and click the 0th index.

jQuery version:

```js
$('.welcomeLoginButton')[0].click();
```

Vanilla JS versions:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("welcomeLoginButton")[0].click();
```

```js
// querySelector without the All just returns the first index of the array
document.querySelector('.welcomeLoginButton').click();
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.welcomeLoginButton')[0].click();
```